# How to get latitude and longitude android in offline mode

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, locationmanager

I am so interested, can i get gps coordinat in offline mode (without internet connection). Is it possible? how can do that?

thanks in advance

Comment: gps is not dependent on internet.you can get lat long using gps,MobileNetwork.

Comment: If you are using google play services then use GoogleApiClient callabacks and get the current location irrespective of internet but drawing that location on map needs internet.

Answer (score 1):

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
if(location==null){
    location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
}
```

This will get lat and long from Network provider.

First it will try to get location from GPS. If gps is off, it will return as null. Thats why I put if(location==null) condition.

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer sir,  if its work for object is always move sir?, and does it need google maps api?

Comment: If you want to move Ur cursor on google maps than Google maps API is required but if u want simply coordinates than there is no need for API.

Yes, Coordinates will change as u move but it can take sometime because this will be provided by ur network operator.

Comment: THis code is broken.  getLastKnownLocation will return null if it doesn't have a location-  if no other app is using that provider.  Meaning it will return null most of the time.  If you actually need a location, use requestLocationUpdates or requestSingleUpdate.  getLastKnownLocation should almost never be used (the only thing is can be used for is an optimization, and even then you have to assume it will usually fail).

Comment: Many apps work offline (without internet) and does NOT use mobile GPS to show longitude-latitude information from location/address. I do not know how they work? Any suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: example app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vishdroid.jyotisha